# Proving function defined by integral is bijective

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-explanation, inverse-function

Good evening,

I'm currently working on this problem that involves proving that the following function is bijective:

$$f:[0,\alpha] \to [0,\beta], \space \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$f(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\theta} g^2(s)ds$$

I've managed to prove that this function is actually injective by the definition. However, I'm finding it difficult to prove that this function is surjective. I've tried using the Mean Value Theorem to prove it, but I can't follow up with any conclusions.

To add up, if $g^2$ is non-zero in any point of the domain, can I conclude that $f$ will surely have an inverse?

I'm assuming $g$ can only reach values from $0$ to positive infinity, and $f(0) = 0, f(\alpha) = \beta $ (due to Darboux's theorem, I believe).

If possible, could you give me a clue on how to proceed with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what assumptions are there on $g$?

Comment: The only assumption I have is that g can reach values from 0 to positive infinity

Comment: that's a very very important assumption, which you should include in your question.

Comment: I take it we can assume $g^2$ is integrable, and so $f'(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} g^2(\theta)$. This implies that $\sqrt{2f'(\theta)} = g(\theta)$. Isn't this sufficient?

Comment: @Gregory why does that prove surjectivity for all values of $\beta$? As an explicit counter example, take $g(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}$. Then, $f(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(\theta)$; this is a bounded function and doesn't take any values in $[\frac{\pi}{4},\infty)$.

Comment: Regarding the missing assumption, I apologize for it. I knew I was missing something when I made the post - my bad :(

Comment: Some other assumption is still missing: if $f : [0, \alpha] \to [0, \beta]$ is any function, then $f$  viewed as a function $[0, \alpha] \to [0, \beta + 1]$ is not a bijection. Maybe you need to assume that $f(\alpha) = \beta$.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I agree. Although that information isn't given by the work sheet, I've assumed that already and I don't see how that can help

Comment: @DanielF. : You can Edit your question (link just below the tags and to the left of your signature block at the bottom of the Question). and should edit that assumption in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(\theta)$ is a monotonically increasing function because $f'(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}g(\theta)^2 > 0$. Therefore, $f(\theta)$ is injective.

Since $f(\theta)$ is monotonically increasing function, $\min_\theta f(\theta) = f(0)$ and $\max_\theta f(\theta) = f(\alpha)$. And since $f(\theta)$ is continuous, its image is the interval $[f(0), f(\alpha)] = [0, \beta]$. Thus, $f(\theta)$ is also surjective, and therefore bijective.

Comment: Thank you for this! Much obliged :)